How to ask someone to reveal a secret
What’s the expression we tell someone when they’re hiding something and we want to know what is it?
I was thinking “Drop it” or “Hush” but I realized it was something different.

Also, spill the tea (https://usdictionary.com/idioms/spill-the-tea/).

When urging someone else to reveal their secret (an imperative construction)...

spill it, spill the beans, cough up, own up,...

If the subject himself decided to reveal a secret, he might also blow the whistle or 'fess up,... but those wouldn't normally be used as imperatives. And there are other expressions such as let slip which imply the information was revealed accidentally.
Obviously stylistic choice is a major factor, but we'd need a much more precise context to say whether any of the above might be particularly suitable (or unsuitable) in any given case.

You can also use come clean, it's AE and informal:

to confess; tell the truth 
to tell the truth, esp. to admit one's guilt


I had expected her to come clean and confess that she only wrote these books for the money.
If your property is not in the centre of town, come clean; make a virtue of it.


(Collins)

